# ValueListenableBuilder not rebuilding the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to update the MaterialApp widget whenever isTokenExpired becomes true...when isTokenExpired updates I'm calling notifyListeners() and builder is called and print statements are executed, but the ValueListenableBuilder is not rebuilding the MaterialApp Widget.

What I am missing?

Hi here is the code:

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: isTokenExpired,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        print("app refresh token:" + currentUser.value.refreshToken.toString());
        print("BUILD IS CALLED ");
        print("istoken expired | ${isTokenExpired.value}");
       

        return KeyboardDismissOnTap(
          child: MaterialApp(
            title: "testpal_app",
            builder: BotToastInit(),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            navigatorObservers: [BotToastNavigatorObserver()],
            home: isTokenExpired.value
                ? LoginView()
                : StudentWrapper(),
          ),
        );
      },
```

Here is also my ValueNotifier and the method called:

```
ValueNotifier<bool> isTokenExpired = new ValueNotifier(false);

refreshToken() async {
    String url =
        '${GlobalConfiguration().getString('base_url')}user/api/token/refresh/';
    print(url);
    final client = new http.Client();
    var res = await client.post(
      url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
        {
          "refresh": currentUser.value.refreshToken,
        },
      ),
    );
    var data = json.decode(utf8.decode(res.bodyBytes));

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print("refresh token successfull");
      currentUser.value.accessToken = data['access'];
      await setCurrentUser(currentUser.value);
    } else {
      print(res.statusCode);
      print(data);
     
      isTokenExpired.value = true;
      isTokenExpired.notifyListeners();
      print("refresh token expired");
      throw data;
    }
  }
```

Comment: ValueNotifier only notifies the listeners if you are setting a different value. Also, if your ValueListenableBuilder is not on screen (example inside a scaffold drawer that is closed), it won't be called either.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am working on 2 projects right now which use ValueListenableBuilder, and both of them have this problem. The builder is called again, like in your case, the print statement is called, but the Widgets do not re-render.

Comment: I have same problem too. Triggered by a different value the ValueListenableBuilder builder function (with the new value) is called but the returned CustomPaint is not shown on the screen. If the builder contains a Text widget the new value is shown.

Comment: I have been trying to achieve a similar behavior. I could not update my MaterialApp, but I could make it "reload" by pointing it to a different MaterialApp instance. In your case, having a valid token, should point you to your StudentWrapper MaterialApp. If not valid, to your LoginView MaterialApp. It is important to point that I have started flutter very recently, so I hope that leads you into a good solution, as mine is probably not one of the best ones.